# Better way to structure custom compiled libs

Tags: c++, linux, directory-structure

I am custom compiling libcurl , libssl and some other library. I don't want to replace system library, because if I am changing it system wise, it is going to create lib conflict and I need to compile all other component depending on these libs.

So I started using RPATH and started structuring like this:

```
|-- bin
|   |-- app.out
|-- lib
|   |-- libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_system.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libcares.so -> libcares.so.2.0.0
|   |-- libcares.so.2 -> libcares.so.2.0.0
|   `-- pkgconfig
`-- sbin
    `-- nginx
```

This approach worked. Now problem is that , We started using PHP and node which require same application version.

```
|-- bin
|   |-- a.out
|-- lib
|   |-- libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_system.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
|   |-- libcares.so -> libcares.so.2.0.0
|   |-- libcares.so.2 -> libcares.so.2.0.0
|   `-- pkgconfig
|-- php_ext
|   `-- sqlite3.so
|-- node
|   `-- node_modules
|   |-- bin 
|   |   |-- node
`-- sbin
    `-- nginx
```

Now , this svn repo is becoming bigger and bigger after every release. Is there a better way to structure this ? without duplicating lib folder in each app ?

Comment: It's been too long since I've played with subversion to give a formal answer, but can't you put your custom libraries in to a separate subversion repository (or top-level directory?  I forget my terms), and add that repository as a subversion external dependency to each project?  This would give you a single place to edit and store your files, and allow multiple projects to grab the results.

Comment: @vivek-goel - is the second tree for a different thing - or is it just a later version of the first tree ?

Comment: @IwanAucamp It is later version of the first tree.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has used both git and svn extensively for years, I'd seriously consider moving to git and using git submodules. Git is hugely more space-efficient (among many, many other benefits). There are also git-svn bridges that you can make if you're stuck using svn at your company.

Failing that, I'd make an svn externals for each **group** of shared libraries. If you have something that changes often or is logically grouped together, it can go in one svn repo while other libraries that may not change very often.

One of the advantages of git over svn is that git protects you from file corruption. I can painfully remember several occurrences of svn corrupting files (something that wasn't noticed until the client submitted a bug report).

Seriously, save yourself a world of headaches, ditch svn in favour of git.

Answer (score 0):

I was taking a totally different approach when I was working with C++.

I don't treat libs as part of source code.  I only want the "dependency" to exist with my source.  (It is not appropriate to have "version control" for the lib binary anyway)

I have a separate directory to store all libs in a organized manner, something like libname/version/arch.

In the build script, I am referring to something like $LIB_DIR/libname/version/arch/lib-ver.so.

You can have different way to store/distribute the Lib directory, either put it in a network volume, put that in SVN etc.

Comment: @Adiran Shum I am keeping in svn for easy deployment.